# Is there a way to group object fields in Angular?

Tags: angular, pipe

I believe that I am looking for an Angular pipe that will allow for me to group items in an array together based on and defined key from the array. As an example, if I had an array with these `state` and country `keys`:

```
items: any = [
{
    "state": "Illinois",
    "country": "USA"
}, 
{
    "state": "Florida",
    "country": "USA"
}, 
{
    "state": "Ontario",
    "country": "Canada"
}
];
```

As I would iterate through my list, i'd like for the pipe to group the items with the same key together in a list so that when it is displayed to the user they could see like items together.

Do I need to create a custom pipe for this or just filter the items a particular way, or is there a way to accomplish this using a `map` in `rxjs` or a `filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure which guidelines this post didn't follow, but here was my solution after a number of attempts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'groupBy'
})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(collection: any[], property: string): any[] {
        
        // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
        if(!collection) {
            return null;
        }

        const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current) => {
            if (!previous[current[property]]) {
                previous[current[property]] = [current];
            } else {
                previous[current[property]].push(current);
            }
    
            return previous;
        }, {});
    
        // this will return an array of objects, each object containing a group of objects
        return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
    }

}
```

Now it my templates I can use the pipe to group items together:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories | groupBy: 'category'">
   <h3>{{ category.key }}</h3>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of category.value">{{ item.title }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```